# PHP Warning: Cannot load module "openswoole" because conflicting module "swoole" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, swoole, openswoole

I have a warning when I use any php command in terminal:

> PHP Warning:  Cannot load module "openswoole" because conflicting module "swoole" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

What can I uninstall and how on Ubuntu? I don't use swoole and openswoole, but I don't know how to unistall that.